# Truncated Backpropagation Through Time (BPTT) in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, backpropagation, truncated

In pytorch, I train a RNN/GRU/LSTM network by starting the Backpropagation (Through Time) with :

```
loss.backward()
```

When the sequence is long, I'd like to do a **Truncated** Backpropagation Through Time instead of a normal Backpropagation Through Time where the whole sequence is used.

But I can't find in the Pytorch API any parameters or functions to set up the truncated BPTT. Did I miss it? Am I supposed to code it myself in Pytorch ?

Comment: Just use `h = h.detach()` at the point where you want to cut the backprop. See [`repackage_hidden()`](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/word_language_model/main.py#L103) in the language modeling example. It effectively does the truncation.

Comment: Thanks. In this code, which parameter controls the number of sequences I want to BPTT ? For example, the sequence length (args.bptt) is 35 in the code and let's say I want the BPTT to be done over just the last 5 sequences. What parameter is used for 5.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```py
for t in range(T):
   y = lstm(y)
   if T-t == k:
      out.detach()
out.backward()
```

So in this example, `k` is the parameter you use to control the timesteps you want to unroll.

Comment: Shouldnt you also do a `out.backward()` in the if clause as well?

Comment: Yes if you want to backprop at every single valid timestep. The example shown is only doing the update on the very last valid timestep.